# How to use a secure docker registry within a kind kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssl, kind

I am trying to create a secure docker registry to be used inside a development kind cluster. I am going to use a container for the registry and 3 other containers for kind workers. In order to be consistent with the production environment I want to use TLS, so I created a self signed certificate for the docker registry. I connected the containers using docker network. However, when I create a deployment based on an image from that registry, I get `x509 certificate signed by unknown authority` error.

I used this [tutorial](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/private-registries/#use-a-certificate)

```
containerdConfigPatches: # Enable a local image registry, placeholders automatically replaced in bootstrap script -- https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/
- |-
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs.my-registry.tls]
    cert_file = "/etc/docker/certs.d/my-registry/domain.crt"
    key_file  = "/etc/docker/certs.d/my-registry/domain.key"
```

But it does not seem to work.

My kind version:

```
kind v0.17.0 go1.20 linux/amd64
```

The command I use to create the registry:

```
docker run -d \
  --restart=always \
  --name my-registry \
  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM="Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:80 \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  -p 7443:80 \
  registry:2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a self-signed certificate for your docker registry instead of a certificate issued by a trusted certificate authority (CA). The docker daemon does not trust the self-signed certificate, which is causing the x509 error.

This may occur due to the expiration of the current certificate, due to a changed hostname, and other changes.

1. Verify that the `$HOME/.kube/config` file contains a valid certificate, and regenerate a certificate if necessary. The certificates in a kubeconfig file are base64 encoded. The `base64 --decode` command can be used to decode the certificate and `openssl x509 -text -noout` can be used for viewing the certificate information.
2. Unset the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable using:

   unset KUBECONFIG

Or set it to the default KUBECONFIG location:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

Another workaround is to overwrite the existing `kubeconfig` for the "admin" user:

```
mv  $HOME/.kube $HOME/.kube.bak
mkdir $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

For more information refer to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#tls-certificate-errors)